# Set não remove objetos duplicados

Tags: javascript, objetos, referência, set

Eu tenho um array de objetos e sempre para remover os objetos duplicados uso o `new Set(array)`, porém dessa vez não funcionou como esperado.

No exemplo a seguir, fica mais fácil de entender. Estou passando meu array com dois objetos duplicados, o "Multigases" e o "Ventilação Temporária", mas não estou conseguindo entender o porquê de não estar funcionando.

```js
let arrayObjetos = [
  { descricao: 'Multigases', id: 1 },
  { descricao: 'Iluminação Temporária', id: 3 },
  { descricao: 'Ventilação Temporária', id: 2 },
  { descricao: 'Capa de cobertura.', id: 21 },
  { descricao: 'Multigases', id: 1 },
  { descricao: 'Ventilação Temporária', id: 2 },
  { descricao: 'Cadeado', id: 85 }
];
arrayObjetos = [...new Set(arrayObjetos)];

console.log(arrayObjetos);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consoante com a [especificação da linguagem](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-samevaluezero) (em tradução livre):

> Objetos `Set` são coleções de valores da linguagem ECMAScript. Um valor distinto pode ocorrer somente uma vez como elemento de uma coleção `Set`. Valores distintos são discriminados utilizando o algoritmo de comparação [`SameValueZero`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-samevaluezero).

Esse algoritmo de comparação é similar ao utilizado pelo já familiar operador `===`. A única diferença é que, para o `Set`, valores `NaN` são sempre iguais:

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN); // false
console.log([...new Set([NaN, NaN])]); // [NaN] (somente 1, mas passamos 2)
```

Assim, sabendo que o algoritmo de comparação é similar ao `===`, podemos afirmar que objetos serão considerados iguais somente no caso de terem a mesma referência.

Isso não é, evidentemente, o caso no seu exemplo, já que você está criando os objetos na forma literal, que cria uma referência diferente para cada objeto.

Portanto, mesmo que alguns objetos tenham as mesmas propriedades com seus respectivos valores iguais, *as referências não serão as mesmas* e, assim, não serão removidos já que, para a linguagem, tratam-se de valores diferentes.

Este exemplo ilustra melhor isso. Note que somente objetos de *mesma referência* são removidos. Note também, que mesmo que `a` tenha a mesma "estrutura" que `fakeA`, isso não é um fator para a discriminação.

```js
const a     = { id: 'a' };
const fakeA = { id: 'a' }; // Igual a `a`, mas com referência diferente.
const b     = { id: 'b' };

const mySet = new Set([a, a, a, fakeA, fakeA, fakeA, b, b, b]);

// Veja que somente trará 3 elementos:
console.log([...mySet]);
```

No seu caso, você pode resolver isso criando um simples algoritmo que determina igualdade pela propriedade `id`. Assim, você pode remover os elementos que tiverem um ID igual. Algo assim:

```js
function removeDuplicateEntriesFromListByPropName(list, prop) {
  const map = Object.create(null);

  for (const item of list) {
    const id = item[prop];

    // Irá inserir no "mapa" somente elementos cujo o ID não estiver lá.
    if (!map[id]) {
      map[id] = item;
    }
  }

  // No final, retorne os valores do mapa:
  return Object.values(map);
}

const list = [
  { descricao: 'Multigases', id: 1 },
  { descricao: 'Iluminação Temporária', id: 3 },
  { descricao: 'Ventilação Temporária', id: 2 },
  { descricao: 'Capa de cobertura.', id: 21 },
  { descricao: 'Multigases', id: 1 },
  { descricao: 'Ventilação Temporária', id: 2 },
  { descricao: 'Cadeado', id: 85 }
];

console.log(removeDuplicateEntriesFromListByPropName(list, 'id'));
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda e explicação