# Como funciona o uso de "Set" para remover valores repetidos de um array em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, set

É de conhecimento *quase geral* que, em JavaScript, pode-se utilizar este artifício com `Set` e *spread operator* para [remover *valores* duplicados de um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150413/69296):

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3];
const deduped = [...new Set(arr)];

console.log(deduped); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Mas como isso realmente funciona?

- Por que e como o `Set` remove os valores duplicados?
- O que o *spread operator* `...` está fazendo ali?
- Quando e por que às vezes isso *não funciona* com objetos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Por que o `Set` remove elementos duplicados?

O termo *Set*, inglês para "conjunto", advém do conceito matemático de [Conjunto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto). Da definição, um conjunto é composto por elementos (ou nenhum elemento, o conjunto vazio). [Um conjunto não possui a noção de elementos duplicados.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/223506/629569)

Dessa definição, é possível apenas afirmar que um conjunto contém ou não contém um elemento qualquer. Não é cabível, portanto, dizer que um elemento está presente mais de uma vez (ao contrário do que é possível em uma lista, por exemplo).

Então não faz sentido que linguagens que implementam esse conceito (como o `Set`, do JavaScript) permitam a inclusão de um mesmo elemento diversas vezes em um *set*. Tendo isso em vista, é esperado que estruturas de dados que representem a ideia de conjunto matemático possuam um mecanismo para prevenir a inserção de um mesmo elemento mais de uma vez.

#### Como o `Set` remove elementos duplicados?

Elementos podem ser adicionados a um *set* pelo método `Set.prototype.add`. Para impedir que valores iguais sejam adicionados ao conjunto, o [algoritmo](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-set.prototype.add) do método faz uma verificação antes de, de fato, inserir o elemento.

Assim, se o programador chama o método `add` passando um valor que já existe no conjunto, a inserção não ocorrerá novamente – o *set* permanecerá inalterado. Exemplo:

```
const set = new Set(); // Set(0) {}
set.add('foo'); // Set(1) {"foo"}
set.add('bar'); // Set(2) {"foo", "bar"}

// Elemento "foo" já existe, `set` será mantido inalterado.
set.add('foo'); // Set(2) {"foo", "bar"}
```

Vale ressaltar também que, na instanciação de um novo `Set`, o construtor pode receber um iterável com os elementos iniciais a serem adicionados. Desse modo, a implementação irá percorrer por cada valor do iterável (que pode ser passado para o [primeiro argumento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set#parameters)) e chama o `Set.prototype.add` para cada elemento. Assim, se o iterável fornecido possuir elementos duplicados, o *set* em questão não sofrerá a inserção de valores duplicados.

O mecanismo de comparação utilizado pelo `Set` para determinar se dois elementos são iguais é o **[`SameValueZero`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-samevaluezero)**.

Em suma, o JavaScript não permite que uma instância de `Set` possua elementos duplicados.

#### E o artifício para remover valores duplicados do array? Como funciona?

Como vimos acima, o construtor `Set` aceita um iterável em seu primeiro argumento, utilizando o método `add` ao iterar sobre cada valor iterado, o que evita inserções repetidas.

Como arrays em JavaScript são iteráveis, ao fornecer um array ao primeiro argumento do construtor `Set`, cada valor do array será percorrido, de modo que cada elemento único do array será adicionado à instância em construção. Por exemplo:

```
const set1 = new Set([1, 2, 3, 1]);

// É o mesmo que fazer:
const set2 = new Set();
set2.add(1);
set2.add(2);
set2.add(3);
set2.add(1); // Como já existe, o `add` não alterará o conjunto
```

Desse modo, cria-se um novo conjunto com cada elemento, não repetido, do array. Esse mesmo procedimento pode ser feito para qualquer iterável, como strings.

Uma vez que o *set* tenha sido criado, os elementos duplicados do array já foram removidos. A partir daí, é necessário criar um novo array, já que a maioria das pessoas, ao fornecer um array, esperam um array de volta. Claro que o `Set` é um detalhe da implementação do "algoritmo" para remover elementos duplicados de um array.

É isso que o *spread operator* faz. Quando utilizado dentro de um array literal, o *spread* itera sobre cada elemento de um iterável (como é o caso do *set*, criado anteriormente) e adiciona, elemento a elemento, ao array em que foi aplicado.

Uma vez que o novo array tenha sido criado, não há mais o que fazer. Acabou. Você já tem um novo array sem elementos repetidos.

#### Quando e por que às vezes isso não funciona com objetos?

Como vimos acima, o algoritmo utilizado pelo método `Set.prototype.add` para determinar se dois membros são iguais (ou diferentes) é o [`SameValueZero`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-samevaluezero). A comparação `SameValueZero`, que, para objetos, funciona similarmente ao operador `===`, compara-os via referência.

Para `SameValueZero`, dois objetos serão iguais apenas se tiverem a mesma referência.

Desse modo, embora possuam todos os membros iguais, todos estes objetos são diferentes para o `SameValueZero` (tanto é que o *set* criado não os remove por duplicidade). Veja:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 1 }
]; // Podem parecer objetos iguais, mas possuem referências diferentes,
   // já que não se tratam do **mesmo** objeto.
   
// Logo, o `Set` não os remove por "duplicidade":
const set = new Set(arr);

// O "novo array" irá conter todos os mesmos três objetos:
const newArr = [...set];

console.log('Initial:', arr);  //=> [{ id: 1 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 1 }]
console.log('Final:', newArr); //=> [{ id: 1 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 1 }]
```

Contudo, neste outro exemplo abaixo, trata-se de uma lista de três elementos, sendo os três o mesmo objeto. Nesse caso, o *set* o remove por duplicidade. Veja:

```js
const obj = { id: 1 };

const arr = [
  obj,
  obj,
  obj
]; // Todos os três elementos são objetos iguais (possuem a mesma referência).
   
// Logo, o `Set` os remove por duplicidade:
const set = new Set(arr);

// O "novo array" irá conter apenas um elemento.
const newArr = [...set];

console.log('Initial:', arr);  //=> [{ id: 1 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 1 }]
console.log('Final:', newArr); //=> [{ id: 1 }]
```

Nos casos em que objetos devem ser removidos por algum critério de duplicidade, portanto, o `Set` pode não ser ideal. Na maioria dos casos, é ideal criar um algoritmo de comparação na mão. [Veja mais nesta outra resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474344/69296)

Comment: +1 Boa P/R. _"..ao fornecer um array ao primeiro argumento do construtor `Set`, cada valor do array será percorrido,"_, então podemos dizer que `Set` influencia na complexidade de um algoritmo? eu estava com essa dúvida

Comment: @CmteCardeal, sim. Algumas operações do `Set`, como `has` são, _per-spec_, sublineares na maioria dos casos; podendo, a depender da implementação, chegar em algo melhor ([veja mais](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31092145/7445826)). No entanto, é claro que, para construir um _set_ a partir de um array, será linear, já que cada elemento do array terá que ser percorrido. Então, sim, pode afetar. No caso desta pergunta, a linearidade advém da própria necessidade do algoritmo. Não penso que seja possível remover todos os duplicados de um array com coisa menor que `O(n)`.