# Retornar valores em comum de várias matriz de objetos em Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Galera fiz um exemplo simples para ilustrar meu problema. Tenho 3 arrays de objetos a `datasOne`, `datasTwo` e `datasThree` e o que quero é retornar um novo array somente com os objetos que tem nos 3 arrays. Por exemplo, se tiver somente o Gustavo nos 3 arrays, então ele que será retornado. Mas tem um detalhe que se o `datasThree` for um array vazio, então irá trazer os dados em comum somente do `datasOne` e `datasTwo` e se somente o `datasTwo` que tiver dados e os outros dois arrays tiver vazios, então irá retornar os dados somente do `datasTwo`. Em outras palavras é retornar os dados em comum somente dos arrays que tiverem dados. Eu consegui fazer esse algoritmo e funciona da maneira que quero, mas gostaria de saber outra forma de fazer isso menos verbosa e talvez mais simples e também funcionar para se caso eu adicionar mais arrays para comparar como um `datasFour` por exemplo. Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Meu código abaixo:

```js
let datasOne = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Ana' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alice' }
]

let datasTwo = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alice' }
]

let datasThree = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Ana' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Kelly' },
  { id: 4, name: 'David' }
]

let filtered

if (datasOne.length > 0 && datasTwo.length > 0 && datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasOne.filter(firstData => {
    let f1 = datasThree.filter(
      secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id
    ).length
    let f2 = datasTwo.filter(
      secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id
    ).length
    if (f1 && f2) {
      return true
    }
  })
} else if (datasOne.length > 0 && datasTwo.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasOne.filter(firstData => {
    return datasTwo.filter(secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id).length
  })
} else if (datasOne.length > 0 && datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasOne.filter(firstData => {
    return datasThree.filter(secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id)
      .length
  })
} else if (datasTwo.length > 0 && datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasTwo.filter(firstData => {
    return datasThree.filter(secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id)
      .length
  })
} else if (datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasThree
} else if (datasTwo.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasTwo
} else if (datasOne.length) {
  filtered = datasOne
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa de uma função que retorna a intersecção entre 2 arrays. A princípio poderia ser algo assim:

```js
function interseccao2(array1, array2) {
    return array1.filter(e1 => array2.some(e2 => e1.id === e2.id));
}
```

Só que esta função não é lá muito eficiente, pois para cada elemento de `array1`, ela percorre novamente o `array2` desde o início, até encontrar o elemento (no pior caso, quando o elemento não existe, percorrerá todo o `array2`). Claro que para poucos arrays pequenos a diferença será imperceptível, mas se tiver muitos arrays com vários elementos (e/ou ainda com poucos elementos em comum), poderá ficar lento sim.

Uma outra forma é usar um `Set`, que é uma estrutura otimizada para buscas (além de não permitir elementos repetidos - ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313890/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510118/112052)). O problema é que `Set` não funciona para objetos, então podemos usá-lo para guardar apenas o campo que nos interessa, que é o `id`:

```js
function interseccao2(array1, array2) {
    var idsB = new Set(array2.map(b => b.id));
    var res = [];
    for (const elemento of array1) {
        if (idsB.has(elemento.id)) {
            res.push(elemento);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu crio um `Set` contendo os id's do `array2`. Depois eu filtro o `array1`, pegando os elementos cujos id's estão neste `Set`. O resultado será a intersecção entre os elementos. Também daria para escrever desta forma:

```js
function interseccao2(array1, array2) {
    var idsB = new Set(array2.map(b => b.id));
    return array1.filter(e => idsB.has(e.id));
}
```

Fazendo um [teste básico](https://jsbench.me/5pku30pv45/1), as duas opções com `Set` se mostraram bem mais rápidas que a primeira solução acima usando `some`.

Mas novamente, para poucos arrays pequenos, a diferença será imperceptível (afinal, [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/)). De qualquer forma, é interessante atentar para esses detalhes, pois pode ser que um dia você precise processar muitos arrays maiores e saber desses pormenores pode fazer a diferença.

---

Enfim, agora que já sabemos obter a intersecção entre dois arrays, basta generalizar para vários, excluindo os vazios. Ficaria assim:

```js
// calcula a intersecção entre 2 arrays
function interseccao2(array1, array2) {
    var idsB = new Set(array2.map(b => b.id));
    return array1.filter(e => idsB.has(e.id));
}

// calcula a intersecção entre vários arrays, ignorando os vazios
function interseccao(...arrays) {
    // pega somente os arrays não vazios
    var naoVazios = arrays.filter(array => array.length > 0);
    if (naoVazios.length == 0)
        return []; // se todos são vazios, não tem o que calcular

    var res = naoVazios.shift(); // começa com o primeiro array
    for (var array of naoVazios) { // calcula a intersecção com os restantes, de 2 em 2
        res = interseccao2(res, array);
    }
    return res;
}

let datasOne = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Ana' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alice' }
];
let datasTwo = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alice' }
];
let datasThree = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Ana' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Kelly' },
  { id: 4, name: 'David' }
];

console.log(interseccao(datasOne, datasTwo, datasThree));
// [ { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' }, { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' } ]

// testando com o segundo array vazio
console.log(interseccao(datasOne, [], datasThree));
// [ { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' }, { id: 2, name: 'Ana' }, { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' } ]
```

Repare também que coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente criamos a função **dataFilterByIntersectionName** com o *spread operator* no argumento para criarmos um array com os arrays de objetos sem precisar saber previamente o tamanho dele.

Dentro da função começamos filtrando os arrays de dados vazios, no caso em que o resultado desse filtro gere um array de tamanho 1, isso quer dizer que só tem uma fonte de dados então retornaremos esse próprio array como você mesmo pediu no enunciado.

Agora criamos a constante **returnedData** para segurar todos valores que passarem pelo teste da repetição. Pegamos o primeiro array de objetos do **filteredData** para ser a base da comparação de nomes com nomes para obter o número de vezes em que o nome repete. Como vamos fazer a comparação? Vamos usar a primeira *forEach* para percorrer cada **obj1** de dentro do primeiro array de objetos do array **filteredData**, e dentro do escopo desse primeiro *forEach* criamos um let **count** para segurar a contagem do número de vezes que o nome repete.

O segundo *forEach* do **filteredData** é para abrir o array de array de objetos, e o segundo *forEach* para abrir o array de objetos (repare que o argumento **...data** cria um array de arrays de objeto), e por que isso? Porque comparando nome a nome pela varredura de todos objetos saberemos que se a quantidade de vezes em que o nome repete for numericamente maior ou igual ao tamanho do array de arrays de objetos, então esse nome está contido pelo menos uma vez em cada array de objetos, podendo haver o caso de existir dois Gustavo, por exemplo, em um único array também. Por isso a condicional comparando o nomes, pois se for verdadeiro a gente acrescenta a contagem em 1, depois de percorrer todos os arrays de objetos do array de arrays criamos a condicional para puxarmos o objeto com os dados para o **returnedData** caso verifique a condicional segundo a comparação do valor **count** com o tamanho do **...data**, depois disso o primeiro *forEach* continua para o próximo objeto e zera a contagem, assim até varrer totalmente os nomes e retornar os dados.

```
const dataFilterByIntersectionName = (...data) => {
  const filteredData = data.filter((array) => array.length > 0);

  if (filteredData.length === 1)
    return filteredData;

  const returnedData = [];

  filteredData[0].forEach((obj1) => {
    let count = 0;
    filteredData.forEach((array) => {
      array.forEach((obj2) => {
        if (obj1.name === obj2.name) {
          count++;
        }
      });
    });

    if (count >= filteredData.length)
      returnedData.push(obj1);
  })

  return returnedData;
}
```